# Send the value selected by user to an other process with named pipe

Tags: c, switch-statement, named-pipes

I have written two programs, the first one has a switch case and create a named pipe "pipeselect" to read the value switch by user and the second one read the value back with the named pipe. But no matter I type 1 or 2, the second program also display "Option 1 is selected". What is the problem with my scripts?

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
 char pipeselect[] = "/tmp/pipeselect";
 int bufs[2];
 int fds;
 int select1;

 /* Pipe Creation */
 if (access(pipeselect, F_OK) == -1) {
  fds = mkfifo(pipeselect, 0700);
  if (fds != 0) {
   printf("Pipe creation error\n");
   exit(1);
  }
 }

  printf("1. Option 1\n");
  printf("2. Option 2\n");
  printf("Please select an option: ");
  scanf("%d", &select1);

if (select1 == 1 || select1 == 2)
{
  if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    printf("Pipe open error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  bufs[0] = select1;     // put value entered by user into buffer
  write(fds, bufs, 1);   // write 1 byte from the buffer
  close(fds);

  printf("Option %d is selected\n", select1);
}
else {
  printf("Wrong Input!\n");
}

unlink(pipeselect);
exit(0);
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()

{
 char pipeselect[] = "/tmp/pipeselect";
 int bufs[2];
 int fds;
 int select1;

  if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    printf("Pipe open error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  select1 = read(fds, bufs, 1);   // write 1 byte from the buffer
  printf("Option %d is selected\n", select1);
  close(fds);

exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because [**`read()`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returns the number of bytes successfuly read, in your case `1` because you are reading `1`. Guessing how things shoul work is not a good idea, half of the time you will be wrong.

What you must do is read library functions documentation to understand how they should be used, for instance you ignore the return valud of [**`scanf()`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

You should try this<sup>1</sup>, instead of

```
write(fds, bufs, 1);
```

go with

```
if (write(fds, &select1, sizeof(select1)) != sizeof(select1))
    fprintf("error writing to pipe: %d:%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
/* Inlucde <errno.h> and <string.h> for this error message to work */
```

And in the other program, change

```
select1 = read(fds, bufs, 1);
```

to

```
if (read(fds, &select1, sizeof(select1)) == sizeof(select1))
    printf("Option %d is selected\n", select1);
```

Also, check what `scanf()` returned instead of assuming that `select1` was initialized and using it, in case it wasn't your program would invoke undefined behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Be careful, if the endianness is not the same when sending data like this it will not work directly. In this case it's obviously ok, but if it were netwrok code this is not a good way of doing it because you should take endianness into account. Other than that, this is ok.</sub>

Comment: @JeffSon I just added that to the answer.

Comment: Very nice!! Finally I got my expected result...nice to meet you iharob!